# Why PHP Static method is accessible with the object.?

Tags: php, static-methods

**Why an object of a PHP class can call a static method?**

```
<?php
        
        class Student
        {
            public static $university;
            public static function info()
            { 
                echo "Static Method is called ";
            }
        }
        
        $s1 = new Student();
        $s1->university = "BBBB";   //Give error , Its OK
        $s1->info();                //Why dont give the error, as info() is a static method
```

In the above code, I want to know why `$s1->info()`; does not give the error in PHP?

Comment: Static can basically be understood to mean that you're declaring stuff directly on the class itself, not the instance. And when you create a new instance, it also "inherits" the stuff declared on the class itself because it's part of the class. PHP apparently is ok letting you do this. But it doesn't work the other way around in terms of trying to use `$this` without an instance.

Comment: Because it is _PHP_.

Comment: Note it's also possible to declare a variable as static within a method. And the variable will be remembered between each call to the method. Thus the variable essentially lives on the method itself. You'll see this used with singleton when a method is called like instance() and it would remember the instance via usage of static otherwise instantiate the class. While this could also be accomplished by storing the instance variable as a static member on the class itself, that's overscoping if the static variable can be restricted to the method itself.

Comment: I'm sure there's an explanation within the PHP source code but I haven't been able to find a direct acknowledgement in the docs. Basically it seems that only static methods interact this way. Static properties will flag an error if trying to access non-statically but this doesn't apply to methods. So there doesn't seem to be a clear "why" that's easy to find.